# Using default values when using generics

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have something like this:

```
type QueryResult<ResultType = string, ErrorType = string> = {
  result: ResultType,
} | {
  errors: ErrorType,
}
```

Now, when I create my result, I can do something like:

```
const myResult: QueryResult = {
  result: "My result!",
};
```

Also, when I want to change the `ResultType`, I can add it to the generic:

```
const myResult: QueryResult<number> = {
  result: 10,
  errors: null
};
```

However, what if I want to change the type value for `errors`? Well, I *could* do this:

```
// This works, but I don't want to specify the default value
const myErrorResult: QueryResult<string, MyErrorType> = {
  errors: {
    location: [1, 2],
    message: "Invalid argument!",
  }
};
```

How can I skip specifying the `ResultType`? Is that even possible? The main reason for this is that if I have lots of generics, I don't want to provide the default values for every generic type. I've tried `QueryResult<, string>`, but that throws an error, as well as `QueryResult<ErrorType = MyErrorType>`.

You can find a playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

Thanks in advance!

**NOTE:** This is just an example, and I know that this isn't a very good way of representing errors/results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no direct support for skipping over generic type parameters in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#10571](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571) and [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for longstanding open feature requests for such functionality (although it's not clear in those issues whether skipping should have the compiler *infer* the skipped parameters, or if it should fall back to the *default*, or some combination of those).  Right now you have to either give up on it (by `QueryResult<string, MyErrorType>`) or work around it.

---

One possible approach for a workaround is to come up with a "marker" or "sigil" type which is used to signal that the compiler should fall back to some intended default type.  For now let's call it `Default` (but you can imagine calling it `$` or something shorter).

It's just a marker; you don't want it to be confused with any "actual" type. Here's one way to do that:

```
declare class Default { private prop: string }
```

You will never actually have a value of type `Default`.  And because it's declared to be a `class` with [a `private` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private), no other types should accidentally be assignable to it.

Then we can define `Fallback<T, D>` which evaluates to `T` unless `T` is `Default`, in which case it falls back to `D`:

```
type Fallback<T, D> = T extends Default ? D : T;
```

Your original `QueryResult` we will rename out of the way as `_QueryResult` and not specify any defaults:

```
type _QueryResult<R, E> = { result: R } | { errors: E };
```

And finally, here's `QueryResult`:

```
type QueryResult<R = Default, E = Default> =
  [Fallback<R, string>, Fallback<E, string>] extends [infer R, infer E] ?
  _QueryResult<R, E> : never;
```

The idea is that a `QueryResult<R, E>` will be just like `_QueryResult<R, E>`, except if `R` is `Default` it will fall back to `string`, and if `E` is `Default` it will fall back to `string` also.

---

Let's try it out. The normal usages work similarly to before:

```
const myResult: QueryResult = { result: "My result!" };
// const myResult: _QueryResult<string, string>

const myGenericResult: QueryResult<number> = { result: 10 }
// const myGenericResult: _QueryResult<number, string>
```

But now for `myErrorResult` we can write this:

```
const myErrorResult: QueryResult<Default, MyErrorType> = {
  errors: {
    location: [1, 2],
    message: "Invalid argument!",
  }
};
// const myErrorResult: _QueryResult<string, MyErrorType>
```

which falls back nicely to `_QueryResult<string, MyErrorType>`. If instead of `Default` you had `$`, you could maybe even imagine `LotsOfTypeParameters<$, $, $, string, $, $, number>` not being too cumbersome.

---

Of course this is just a workaround.  If you were relying on *type inference* for `QueryResult`, you might be disappointed with this version, since [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) are hard to infer properly.  It really comes down to your use cases.

Depending on what you want there may be a different version that works better for you.  Or if no workaround meets your needs, you may just want to go to the existing feature requests in GitHub, give them a , and describe your use case and why the only solution that works for you is a genuine way of skipping generic type parameters.  I wouldn't be optimistic about that having much effect, but it wouldn't hurt.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwCIgGZQK4QBd4BveABxgEsA3KAhCgezIC55kCqA7Ac3gF8AUIIIBPMggBiUCBABGUMAGsAPABUANBgB88ALzw18EAA96XYGkw58RAPwZ4bNQG5hYifAD6ARVwgYUQAlEGRbFSCtAFFdA1I4MMI2IIF4AB8SYxgYRhhkNiiBNxFxBD8A4NDwlINrPEJo-QxseoJYwXh4AG1pWQVlCK0Obh5tLV75RVUooc5KXm0AXWMzEAs0LvmsAPhI+C2dqOW7Du9ywJDEgkH4GKd4LhBqAOLBMEYuDngAW0qrtnOf1sTXiVSS8AARABZUTwBK2ACEEKKggA9KjEB8vr9LrY2L5-BcwddhvMeLMRtphO9PkRfgBxNYBShgXHgwFs65cXDfOQBWKZeHggCMAAYBGiMTTsaJGY8qKzifiOcSVNzeQEKWSqe5SvAYVFsrk1Hq4qcIIwwHRKB82F11XyYFoHQFFm5Ot9QsgoDwQGxSbw3EI3li6aJDTkYJyAYSgYQVHVbFoDUaYCaJALiKcApH8iRTp0LVaCDauHbhVoAEyLDQFn5en1+yEASS4tAglGA8FgPB5awISNrnSE-Dc6MxtJ+4dT0bOsc5KgD5P108j6ZA2iAA)

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for the thorough explanation! Unfortunately, I can't change the original type (it's from a library, and I probably should have put that in my question originally). I decided just to provide the defaults myself and give the issues a .

Comment: You could leave the original type alone and make your own alias to it which acts as above, e.g., `type MyQueryResult<R = Default, E = Default> = [Fallback<R, string>, Fallback<E, string>] extends [infer R, infer E] ? QueryResult<R, E> : never;`

Comment: And you can even infer the defaults if you need to, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx5kxW)

Answer (score 1):

jcalz's answer is amazing, but I thought I would suggest another potential workaround.

The easy might be to just create a separate type for this case:

```js
type ErrorQueryType<ErrorType = string> = QueryType<string, ErrorType>;
```

Comment: Well, I still have to type the default types in that case, so it's not really helpful unless I was using this type multiple times (which I'm not, at least of right now). Thanks for your answer anyway!